# Problems loading Ruta TYPESYSTEM

Tags: uima, ruta

I'm having trouble importing a typesystem into Ruta. I have two projects in my workspace:

- UIMA project located ./workspace/UIMA_NLP/
- Ruta project located at ./workspace/RUTA_CLARIFY/

I'm trying to load the Type System Definition file: *./workspace/UIMA_NLP/descriptors/type_system/nlpTypes.xml* created in the UIMA project into the Ruta script.

I've been able to do this successfully if I copy the Type System Definition into the Ruta project into *./workspace/RUTA_CLARIFY/descriptor/nlpTypes.xml* and loading it in the Ruta script with the following:

```
TYPESYSTEM nlpTypes;
```

However, when trying to import directly from the UIMA_NLP project I get **'error  nlpTypes not found'** in the editor. I've tried adding the fully qualified directory of the Type System Descriptor to the descriptorPaths field in the generated ruta engine without any success.

I've tried the following types system imports in script after adding the path to the descriptor paths:

```
TYPESYSTEM type_system.nlpTypes;
TYPESYSTEM descriptors.type_system.nlpTypes;
TYPESYSTEM UIMA_NLP.descriptors.type_system.nlpTypes;
```

What is strange is that I can add the nlpTypes.xml Type System Descriptor in the Type System generated by the Ruta script using the Imported Types and Import By Location and the types defined by the imported nlpTypes.xml appear in the Types. I can also type them in the editor when using auto-complete and the types appear. However, I will still get an error in the editor that **'Type "typename" is not defined in this script/block'** even after using the auto-complete to complete the type name. Because of this I suspect I am not using the TYPESYSTEM import correctly for this case.

Am I using the TYPESYSTEM import incorrectly? Or is the only way to use my predefined Type System Descriptor to copy it to the Ruta project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the absolute path to the folder of the type system to the `descriptiorPaths` configuration parameter of your analysis engine descriptor should work. However, in which xml descriptor did you add it? If it is the generated descriptor of your script, then the modification will be overwritten by the workbench. You need to add the additional path to the template descriptor `BasicEngine.xml` of the project.

If the descriptorPath contains the paths to the descriptors folder of the other project, then the correct import would read: `TYPESYSTEM type_system.nlpTypes;`

Normally, you would reference the UIMA project from the Ruta project: Right-click on the Ruta project->Properties->Project References->Check the UIMA project

The default folders of referenced projects are automatically included in the descriptorPaths when the analysis engine descriptor is built by the workbench. In case of UIMA Pear projects, this would be the `desc` folder. For Java project this would be the output folder, e.g., bin or target/classes.

The strange error you report is really strange. Sounds like a problem of the project setup or descriptors that are not up-to-date. Try to clean the project: Menu->Project->Clean...

The error is maybe false positive due to the project setup. Can you launch the script and get results in the output folder?

I personally recommend using simple Ruta projects only for prototyping. For serious rule projects, especially if there are dependencies to other projects, I'd rather recommend a maven-built project. There is also an archetype for ruta projects in order to ease the setup.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Thanks! I was changing the `descriptorPaths` in the wrong engine. I was also successful referencing the UIMA project, our build did not initially include the descriptors in the output. The second error was because I tried to import the types in the generated descriptor the autocomplete worked but it was unable to run. Though not necessary anymore, importing the types into `BasicTypeSystem.xml` worked. And yes, this is currently a prototype.